# onsen ui : create onsenui elements in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

is it possible to create onsen ui elements in another javascript folder without using Angular, if no as i suppose how can i use angular for only recognizing the ons directive inside my js file, i mean that i'm not going to use angular for nothing else but this because i already went so far with native javascript

i don't know much about angular and i think i have to learn about it but i can't before i finish this app i already started

so if this is a part of my js code

```
var app = {


    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        console.log('console');
        db = opendb();
        //alert(db);
        db.transaction(initdb, initError, initSuccess);
        db.transaction(populatedb, initError, initSuccess);
        getHomeContent();
        //db.transaction(GetData, queryError, querySuccess);
        //GetData();
     },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }



};

app.initialize();
(function(){

   document.getElementById("id_page").style.visibility = 'hidden';

})();
```

what am i suppose to add to make my file recognize onsen directives ?